# Python Dict() with Id number

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to dict(). I try the example of [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). (Python 2.6)

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'happy sad happy cry crazy mad sad'

d = defaultdict(int)

for k in s.split():
    d[k] += 1

print d.items()
```

Results:

```
[('crazy', 1), ('sad', 2), ('mad', 1), ('cry', 1), ('happy', 2)]
```

I just wonder that. Is there any possible to get ID of each dict? Any suggestion?

Expect result:

```
[(1, 'crazy', 1), (2, 'sad', 2), (3, 'mad', 1), (4, 'cry', 1), (5, 'happy', 2)]
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no fixed ordering, so there is no index to assign here.

Comment: You can use a counter to number the results, but the order is meaningless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, do you mean can count the number of results but can't use count for dict id right?

Comment: @ThanaDaray what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: If by 'count' you mean 'a counter', then no, you cannot use a counter to index into dictionary results, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a count to the results using [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), but note that the *order* is meaningless as dictionaries have no set order:

```
[(i,) + item for i, item in enumerate(d.items(), 1)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [(i,) + item for i, item in enumerate(d.items(), 1)]
[(1, 'crazy', 1), (2, 'sad', 2), (3, 'mad', 1), (4, 'cry', 1), (5, 'happy', 2)]
```

Dictionary order depends instead on the history of insertions and deletions. You cannot count on `d.items()` to return key-value pairs in a specific order.

The order *does* remain stable as long as you don't add or remove anything from the dictionary, and `d.keys()`, `d.values()` and `d.items()` will produce lists in the same order; `zip(d.keys(), d.values())` produces the same pairs as `d.items()` does. As such, as long as the dictionary itself isn't changed, you *can* use the specific order for that specific dictionary value and rely on it not to change.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered by default. You might be able to get an ordered dict [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Keep in mind that your key is your id in some way. So as far as you don't have an id as `int`. You can always refer to values by their keys. There is no real point to have an index and a key when you have a dict.

If you want to know the size of the dict, you can always use the function `len`.

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

len(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [('crazy', 1), ('sad', 2), ('mad', 1), ('cry', 1), ('happy', 2)]
>>> [(x, y, z) for x, (y, z) in list(enumerate(l, 1))]
[(1, 'crazy', 1), (2, 'sad', 2), (3, 'mad', 1), (4, 'cry', 1), (5, 'happy', 2)]
```