# Text adventure inventory function with dict

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to programm an inventory for my text adventure game. I want to use a dict to store my inventory but i am having trouble finding a good method of doing so.

```
inventory = {
    'Holzbretter:', 'count': 0,
    'Goldmünzen:', 'count': 5,
    'Karte von Shipwreck-Beach:', 'count': 0
}
```

Here is my dict with the items themselfs and a count for the quantity of each item.
I have tried to do this with for loops and if statements but it just doesnt work. I want it to print 'empty inventory' when EVERY 'count' == 0 but it always prints 'empty inventory' 3 times in a row instead of just once. I also want to print every item one under the other with the index being in brackets (i have gotten this to work with enumerate but then the count would stop working) and it should only print items with a 'count' > 0. So like this:

Inventory:

[1] Goldmünze: 5

And if the count of every item would be 0 then it should look something like this:

Inventory:

Your inventory is empty!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI: Your `inventory` seems a little strange. Your keys are tuples of a name and the string `'count'`. Did you mean to just have the name as the key? (In fact python sees your `dict` as a syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, a dict should look somthing like this (dont use ':' inside the keys itself, rather add it to the print when u need it):

```
inventory = {'Holzbretter': 0,
             'Goldmünzen': 5,
             'Karte von Shipwreck-Beach': 0}
```

secondly: maybe you should split your problem into smaller pieces and start searching if similar questions have been answered:

- [How to check if all values of a dictionary are 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253971/how-to-check-if-all-values-of-a-dictionary-are-0)

> use all()

- [Python Dict() with Id number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854141/python-dict-with-id-number)

> Dictionary order depends instead on the history of insertions and deletions. You cannot count on d.items() to return key-value pairs in a specific order.

---

to guarantee the displaying order you could set up a priorisation list of appearance:

```
prio_list = ['Holzbretter', 'Goldmünzen', 'etc..' ]
```

assuming u are using python3, a inventory checker could look like this:

```
def check_inventory(inv: dict):
    for item in prio_list:
        if inv[item] != 0:
            print(f"[{prio_list.index(item)}] {item}: {inv[item]}")
    if all(value == 0 for value in inv.values()):
        print("Your inventory is empty!")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gorschel your code works perfectly and thanks for the tipps. I didnt even know what all() was before, your f' is also very interesting and very compact. But what about adding new items or adding more of one item e.g. Goldmünze + 15 would i just need to change the dict or the prio_list aswell?

Comment: in case of adding X coins to yout inventory, you could do something like

`inv['Goldmünze'] += X`

keep in mind, that you can always add a new entry by

`inv['new_itemname'] = new_value`